# How to get the class of a VALUE in Ruby C API

Tags: c, ruby, api

I created some classes with Ruby's C API. I want to create a function whose behavior will change depending on the class of the Ruby object.

I tried to use `is_a?` from Ruby, however, I don't think it's the good way to do this. I checked "[Creating Extension Libraries for Ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/extension.rdoc)" without success. The only direct way to check classes is with the default types.

I have my class "Klass" already created:

```
VALUE rb_cKlass = rb_define_class("Klass", rb_cObject);
```

And how I wanted to check if the class is the good one:

```
VALUE my_function(VALUE self, VALUE my_argument) {
    if(rb_check_class(my_argument), rb_cKlass)) {
        // do something if my_argument is an instance of Klass
    } else {
        return Qnil;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `RBASIC(my_argument)->klass` should do.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every ruby object is internally represented by [`RObject`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0472578b26793e45434769200a806cb6190e5700/include/ruby/ruby.h#L889) struct (I will copy the source here for the sake of future readers):

```
struct RObject {
  struct RBasic basic;
  union {
    struct {
      uint32_t numiv;
      VALUE *ivptr;
      void *iv_index_tbl; /* shortcut for RCLASS_IV_INDEX_TBL(rb_obj_class(obj)) */
    } heap;
    VALUE ary[ROBJECT_EMBED_LEN_MAX];
  } as;
};
```

The very first member, [`RBasic`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0472578b26793e45434769200a806cb6190e5700/include/ruby/ruby.h#L854), defines the class:

```
struct RBasic {
    VALUE flags;
    const VALUE klass;
}
```

To get an access to `RBasic` metadata of anything, one might use `RBASIC` macro:

```
RBASIC(my_argument)
```

To get the class directly, one might use [`RBASIC_CLASS`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0472578b26793e45434769200a806cb6190e5700/include/ruby/ruby.h#L878) macro:

```
RBASIC_CLASS(my_argument)
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this recently, and used the `RBASIC_CLASS` macro, but was getting segfaults in certain scenarios for some unexplained reason.

After scanning through `ruby.h`, I found the `CLASS_OF` macro, which returns the class as `VALUE` of a given object.

```
VALUE obj = INT2NUM(10);
VALUE klass = CLASS_OF(obj); // rb_cInteger
```

Using Ruby 2.5

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay close to the `is_a?` Ruby fashion (i.e. check if any of the ancestors is the expected class), you could directly use the C implementation of `is_a?`, `rb_obj_is_kind_of`:

```c
rb_obj_is_kind_of(my_argument, rb_cKlass) // Qtrue OR Qfalse
```

And since `Qfalse == 0`, you can just use that method as a condition:

```c
VALUE my_function(VALUE self, VALUE my_argument) {
    if(rb_obj_is_kind_of(my_argument, rb_cKlass)) {
        // do something if my_argument is an instance of Klass
    } else {
        return Qnil;
    }
}
```

To find this method, just check [`Object#is_a?` documentation](https://devdocs.io/ruby%7E2.7/object#method-i-is_a-3F) and click to toggle source, you'll see the C implementation if it is a C function (hence this will work for most of the standard lib).